# Microsoft teams free account :This card action is disabled because BOT has been blocked by your administrator

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using a microsoft teams free account for testing a personal bot. But when I click on any button in the bot message, it is giving below error.

This card action is disabled because BOT has been blocked by your administrator.

I tried looking for an option in azure portal but I could not find any

Comment: You will need to go to the MS Teams admin centre and enable sideloading and external apps, then restart teams and try again. There are instructions on how to enable these settings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/enable-features-office-365#external-apps).

Comment: Please sideload your App again and check, let us know if you are still facing this issue.